# Using a function with a variable number of arguments

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int var_arg_func(...)
{
    std::cout << "Func called!";
}

int main()
{
    var_arg_func(0, 1, 2);
}
```

As you can see here I can pass a variable number of arguments to the function var_arg_func.

But my question is how can I access those arguments from the function itself? (I'm using C++20)

Comment: Why are you using variable arguments instead of a C++ solution like parameter packs?

Comment: Can I get a simple example of that?

Comment: See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

Comment: Variadic functions are inherited from C and kept around for compatibility with existing code. Since then C++ has added parameter packs which are much safer and I'd argue much easier to use. These are templates with unspecified number of arguments.

Comment: For `var_arg_func(...)`, you would need [`va_arg`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic/va_arg) stuff. But prefer variadic template instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **variadic templates**. One example for printing out all the passed argument is given below:

```
#include <iostream>
//provide an ordinary function to end recursion
void print ()
{
}

template<typename T, typename... Types>
void print (T firstArg, Types... args)
{
    std::cout << firstArg << "\n"; // printing the very first argument passed 
    print(args...); // printing the rest of the argument by calling print()
}

int main()
{
    print(1, 2, 3, "some string literal");//call function template print() with arguments `1`, `2`, `3` and `"some string literal"`
    return 0;
}
```

In the above snippet, if we call `print()` with *one or more* arguments then the templated version of `print` will be used/called which just **prints** the very first argument passed(which is `1` in my example) using `cout` and then calls `print` with the remaining arguments(which are `2`, `3` and `"some string literal`.

Now the whole process repeats. In particular, the very first argument `2` is printed using `cout` and then `print` is called with the remaining arguments(`3`, `"some string literal")`.

This goes on until there are no more arguments to pass and in this case when `print` is called with no arguments then the ordinary non-template function `print` will be used/chosen, thus ending the recursion.

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/Lno4918O0):

```
1
2
3
some string literal
```

Note that there are other ways as well like using **fold expression**(with C++17) to do the same. Also, in the above example, the arguments are passed **by value**. You can modify the program to pass them **by reference** according to your needs.

With C++17, you can use fold expression:

```
#include <iostream>
template<class... Args>
void print(const Args&... args)
{
    (std::cout << ... << args) << "\n"; //uses fold expression
}

int main()
{
    print(1, 2, 3, "some string literal");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: side note: The output of the second way is different.

Comment: Yes i am aware, the output of the second is `123some string literal`. It can be formatted according to the needs of the user by adding a `Helper` class. Since, there is no such constraint in OP's original question, i didn't bother to do so. I wanted to just show/print the arguments without formatting them.